# Android: Set visibility of view on animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-adapter

I am developing an application in which i am having a custom list view. One item of list view contains four text box. The need of app is like when i click on one text box, one image view should be visible, zoom in and then zoom out, and after zoom out the visibility should be gone.

What i tried is :

**In adapter in getView method**

```
if(clickPosition == position){  
    holder.imageViewOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.imageViewOne.startAnimation(zoominout);
    zoominout.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            holder.imageViewOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            clickedPosition = -1;
        }
    });
}
```

**My animation XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3" >
</scale>

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5"
    android:startOffset="2000" >
</scale>

</set>
```

When i run my app the animation is working good.

But the **issue** is :

1) The visibility gone on image view is not working.

2) I am having list like below image :

[image]

When i click on list item one, first textview, Animation is working, But when i click on list view 2 first textview animation is working on both List item 1 and List item 2.

What should i do for this? Am i missing something? Please guide me with your valuable suggestions.

Comment: The visibility gone on image view is not working.
Like the image stays or went invisible? what happens there actually?

Comment: Image stays there after animation complete. I tried notifyDataSetChanged(); too. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an array of status of each images whether it is visible or not. You have to apply checks for visibility on the basis of that array of status on each of the ImageView in your `getView()` method. Now everytime when your animation ends for an ImageView, you have to update the corresponding status of that image in your array of status and just call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.